# OSError: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: python, sockets

I have been working on a program that have been causing me issues and I do not know why. I know this question has been asked multiple times but from what I have read I was not able to solve my specific issues. So the code below is part of a Tkinter function which create a GUI whenever I run my scritpt.
Here is my code:

```
def create_window():
 """
Function to create interactive Tkinter window that allows for operation of ALD valves via a home-built controller.
"""# -------------------------------------- Functions -----------------------
def get_press_feedback():
    global server

    class MyHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

        def handle(self):
            self.msg = self.request.recv(1024)
            if self.msg.decode("utf-8") == 'alarm':
                stop_button_click()
                p_alarm_handle(self.msg.decode("utf-8"))

            elif self.msg.decode('utf-8') == 'normal':
                p_alarm_handle(self.msg.decode('utf-8'))

    server = socketserver.TCPServer(("localhost", 8888), MyHandler)
    server.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.serve_forever()

# ---------------------- Start thread to get pressure feedback ------------------------------------------------
pressure_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_press_feedback)
pressure_thread.start()

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', ask_quit)
root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
# If this script is run directly, the create_window function is called
create_window()
```

I tried to run the netstat but did not get any results.
If someone could please help me.
I will be grateful.

Comment: Evidently your `get_press_feedback()` method is called more than once. As this is just a small fragment, I have no idea why. I suggest you include more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: so this function is part of a very long function tkinter that is called create_window() which is called every time I run the program to create the gui